# Ajax: 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am using ajax to get events from my database. Retrieving the results does not work, nothing is displayed, and in the console I get the following error message:

> POST http://www.example.com/system/live_filter.php 500 (Internal Server Error) jquery.min.js:4

Here is my **HTML/JS**:

```
<div id="results">

<script type="text/javascript">

    // 1. When user comes on page from homepage, results will be fetched with ajax
    function updateResults() { 

        // 2. Create array with values of all filter fields
        var value_town_id = $('#town_id').val();
        var value_type = $('#filter_type').val();
        var value_date = $('#filter_date').val();
        var array_filter_values = new Array(value_town_id, value_type, value_date);
        array_filter_values.join(', ');
        query_value = array_filter_values;

    // 3. Start ajax
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "system/live_filter.php",
            data: { query: query_value },
            cache: false,
            success: function(html){
                $("#results").html(html);
            }
        });

    };

    // 4. FIRE FUNCTION!
    updateResults();

</script>

</div>
```

Here is my **live_filter.php** to which the values are sent via Ajax:

```
require_once 'db.php';

// Define Output HTML Formating
$html = '';
$html .= '<div class="event">';
$html .= '<h3>titleString</h3>';
$html .= '<p>typeString</p>';
$html .= '<p>dateString</p>';
$html .= '</div>';

// Get values
$values_string = $_POST['query'];

// Explode to array
$values_array = explode(',', $values_string);
$town_id = $values_array[0];
$type = $values_array[1];
$date = $values_array[2];

// Prepare values for database results query
$town_id = $db->real_escape_string($town_id);
$type = $db->real_escape_string($type);
$date = $db->real_escape_string($date);


// Build Query
$query = "SELECT * FROM events WHERE towns_id=$town_id AND type='$type' AND date>=$date";

// Do Search
$results = $db->query($query);
while($result = $results->fetch_assoc()) {

            // Format Output Strings And Hightlight Matches
            $display_title = $result['title'];
            $display_type = $result['type'];
            $display_date = $result['date'];

            // Insert title
            $output = str_replace('titleString', $display_title, $html);
            // Insert type
            $output = str_replace('typeString', $display_type, $output);
            // Insert date
            $output = str_replace('dateString', $display_date, $output);

            // Output
            echo($output);
}
```

Anyone has an idea where the problem is?

I get the following error message: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AND type='' AND date>=''' at line 1

Comment: You need to check the PHP error log on the server for the reason.

Comment: The answer below indicates at least one problem but what you should take from this is how to debug it next time... AJAX Is simply loading a page in the same way your browser does, getting the "source" and putting it in a variable. In this case, you can use Firebug or Chrome developer tools' net tab to see the result of the request. If it were a GET request, you could see the problem easily by just browsing to the URL. Since it's a POST, you can create a fake form to post the appropriate fields to the url or, more simply, change `$_POST['query']` to `$_REQUEST['query']` and just browse there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's tidy this up and simplify it a bit...

```
function updateResults() { 
    query = {"town_id": $('#town_id').val(),
             "value_type": $('#filter_type').val(),
             "value_date": $('#filter_date').val()
            }

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "system/live_filter.php",
        data: query,
        cache: false,
        success: function(html){
            $("#results").html(html);
        }
    });

};
```

and then in the PHP:

```
require_once 'db.php';

// Define Output HTML Formating
$html = '';
$html .= '<div class="event">';
$html .= '<h3>titleString</h3>';
$html .= '<p>typeString</p>';
$html .= '<p>dateString</p>';
$html .= '</div>';

$town_id = $_REQUEST['town_id'];
$type = $_REQUEST['value_type'];
$date = $_REQUEST['value_date'];

// Prepare values for database results query
$town_id = $db->real_escape_string($town_id);
$type = $db->real_escape_string($type);
$date = $db->real_escape_string($date);


// Build Query
$query = "SELECT * FROM events WHERE towns_id='$town_id' AND type='$type' AND date>='$date'";

/*Should it definitely be towns_id and not town_id?*/

// Do Search
$results = $db->query($query);
while($result = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
            // Insert title
            $output = str_replace('titleString', $result['title'], $html);
            // Insert type
            $output = str_replace('typeString', $result['type'], $output);
            // Insert date
            $output = str_replace('dateString', $result['date'], $output);

            // Output
            echo($output);
}
```

Of course if you're willing to move the template, it gets even simpler...

```
require_once 'db.php';

$town_id = $db->real_escape_string($_REQUEST['town_id']);
$type = $db->real_escape_string($_REQUEST['value_type']);
$date = $db->real_escape_string($_REQUEST['value_date']);

$query = "SELECT * FROM events WHERE towns_id='$town_id' AND type='$type' AND date>='$date'";

$results = $db->query($query);
while($result = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
    $html  = '<div class="event">';
    $html .= '<h3>{$result['title']}</h3>';
    $html .= '<p>{$result['type']}</p>';
    $html .= '<p>{$result['date']}</p>';
    $html .= '</div>';
    echo $html;
}
```

As to why it's erroring...

Firstly, are you sure the variables are being populated? The error you gave in comments would occur if `town_id` was missing. Since you're not quoting that field, it would result in broken SQL. It also makes the escaping pointless as the output expects to be in quotes.

I'd also check that the format of the date coming from your form is one that your database understands...

Try changing the PHP to be as follows:

```
require_once 'db.php';

$town_id = $db->real_escape_string($_REQUEST['town_id']);
$type = $db->real_escape_string($_REQUEST['value_type']);
$date = $db->real_escape_string($_REQUEST['value_date']);

$query = "SELECT * FROM events WHERE towns_id=$town_id AND type='$type' AND date>=$date";

echo $query;
```

Then take the SQL it gives you and copy/paste it into your database admin tool and see what happens. Once you've fixed the syntax errors there, you'll know how to fix the query in your PHP

Comment: works wonderful, thanks! One question: Why did you replace $_POST[...] with $_REQUEST[...]? What is the advantage of using the latter?

Comment: My pleasure. `$_REQUEST` is a combination of `$_POST` and `$_GET` so is handy for debugging. You can browse to eg `http://www.example.com/system/live_filter.php?town_id=1&value_type=something&value_date=2013-01-01` and see the output of the script directly in your browser. Since you can skip the AJAX step, debugging is easier. There is a school of thought that POST is more secure since it makes csrf attacks _marginally_ harder. I tend to agree and swap back to `$_POST` when I've finished debugging.

Answer (score 2):

Can you print the Post value if the variable **$town_id is empty** then only sql generate error

```
SELECT * FROM events WHERE towns_id = AND type='$type' AND date>='$date'
```

in case if you want to execute the query with towns_id is empty. append  single with all variables

```
SELECT * FROM events WHERE towns_id = '$town_id' AND type='$type' AND date>='$date'
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the date in quotes in the query:

```
$query = "SELECT * 
          FROM events 
          WHERE towns_id=$town_id AND type='$type' AND date>='$date'";
```

You should also add error checking to your code:

```
$results = $db->query($query) or die($db->error);
```

Another problem: In your Javascript, you're joining the query values with `', '` (with a space after the comma), but in PHP you're exploding with just `','` (no space). You should be consistent. Even better would be to send all the query values as separate parameters:

```
data: { id: value_town_id, type: value_type, date: value_date }
```

Then you can access them in PHP with `$_POST['id']`, `$_POST['type']`, and `$_POST['date']`.

Comment: I get the following error message: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AND type='' AND date>=''' at line 1

Comment: Can you `echo $query;` and show the result of that?

Comment: Here comes the output of echo $query:   SELECT * FROM events WHERE towns_id= AND type='0' AND date>=date('2014-05-17')  Also what I noticed: I optimized my javascript, as suggested by you, and since then I dont get any 500 error anymore, but still NO results are shown and i get the error message mentioned above

Comment: The browser isn't sending a town ID.

Comment: Wonderful, your answer helped. One problem has remained: My if statement in the live_filter.php does not work ("0" is the value for the option "show all types"): if ($town_id !== '0') {
 $query_type = " AND type='$type'";
} else {
 $query_type = '';
}
$query = "SELECT * FROM events WHERE towns_id=$town_id"
. $query_type
. " AND date>='$date'";    Can you see the error?

Comment: Shouldn't that be `if ($type !== '0')`?

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing jumping out at me as syntactically wrong with your PHP. The problem may lie with your MySQL, an include, or anything else. Check your PHP error log for where to look. If you can't find your error log, try

```
php -l file.php
```

to run a lint check on all your includes and the file itself in the first instance. Then follow the suggestions above regarding calling it in your browser and looking at any errors.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your javascript.

```
array_filter_values.join(', ');
query_value = array_filter_values;
```

This is wrong, try this:

```
query_value =array_filter_values.join(', ');
```

array_filter_values.join(', ') returns the array joined to a string, it doesn't convent the array to a joined string.

Comment: You don't need to use the `date()` function, MySQL will convert automatically.